# No value for argument 'choice' in function call pylint(no-value-for-parameter)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pylint

Пытался написать код, который генерирует все возможные комбинации на Python 3.9, начал выдавать ошибку:

> No value for argument 'choice' in function call pylint(no-value-for-parameter)

Помогите, пожалуйста.

Вот сам код:

```
import itertools


def select():
    print("""
            a. a-z
            b. A-Z
            c. 0-9
                    """)
    choice = c = input('>>> ')
    if choice == 'a':
        a = ltr
        print(a)
    elif choice == 'b':
        b = ltr_upper
        print(b)
    elif choice == 'c':
        c = num
        print(c)
    else:
        print('Enter a valid number of operation.')
        select()


def number_of_characters():
    print("text")
    noc = input('>>> ')
    print(noc)


def generating(choice, noc):
    for i in itertools.product(choice, repeat=noc):
        print(''.join(i))

# lists 
ltr = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z']
ltr_upper = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','G','K','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','U','V','W','X','Y','Z']
num = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0']

select()
number_of_characters()
generating()
```

Comment: Функция generating, ожидает два параметра, вы передаёте ноль...

Comment: Думаю, поможет - https://m.habr.com/ru/post/50381/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> No value for argument 'choice' in function call pylint(no-value-for-parameter)
>
> ```
> def generating(choice, noc):
>     for i in itertools.product(choice, repeat=noc):
>         print(''.join(i))
>
> generating()  # <------- проблема здесь
> ```

Решение репорта `no-value-for-parameter` от `pylint`: передайте два параметра в функцию `generating`, и ошибка `pylint` уйдёт.

Пример:

```
generating(choice=3, noc=5)
```